# PHP file_get_contents() and curl_exec() fail from website but work from command line

Tags: php, command-line, file-get-contents, php-8.1

Created .test.php file with one line of code:

```
<?php
var_dump(file_get_contents('https://checkip.amazonaws.com'));
?>
```

When I open .test.php from browser, it shows bool(false) but when I run it from command line, it shows my WAN IP as expected.

```
php -f .test.php
```

I am using CentOS 9, nginx 1.20.1, and PHP 8.1.3 (Although I've also tried RHEL8 and Apache)

I tried setting **/etc/php-fpm.d/www.conf** to use my userid and group to make sure it was not a permission problem.

phpinfo() shows **allow_url_fopen** is set to On and that curl 7.76.1 is enabled and that OpenSSL is enabled with version 3.0.1

I also tried with an http: URL

I also tried using **curl()** libraries in the .php file and those fail in the same manner.

Calling **exec()** from .php file works if it calls **php -v** or another .php file but not if it calls **curl**

Not sure what else to try, so I will probably nuke the whole server again.

**UPDATE: Found this in /var/log/nginx/error.log**
`FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(https://checkip.amazonaws.com): Failed to open stream: Permission denied`

Now what?

Comment: Good thought. I added this at the top of my .php file but it didn't help `ini_set('allow_url_fopen', '1');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once I found the error log, I was able to find my answer. It was a Linux permission setting and running the following command fixed it:
`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect on`

Answer (score 1):

There might be different settings of your PHP environment used in Command Line Interpreter/Interface `CLI` vs Common Gateway Interface `CGI` .

First compare what `.ini` files are loaded in both environment, ie.

1. for `CLI` run `php -i`
2. for `CGI` create a file `phpinfo.php` with only content `<?php echo phpinfo();` and open it in the web browser.

Compare the results and see what `modules` are loaded and/or what `.ini` files are loaded.

Comment: What a great suggestion. I ran `php -i` from command line and then compared the output to `exec('php -i')` from a website call. The command line had a few extra settings (like SHELL=), but nothing that would explain this. I have also setup HTTPS for the site and that didn't help :(